# Writing Makefiles for headers outside `usr/include`

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

So the initial problem I'm having is that wanting to use headers and their libs like `module.h` and `init.d` and `pci.h` for instance can't be used by simply going `#include <pci.h>` because if you check the actual `pci.h` file you will find that its allot shorter then the usual `pci.h` (40 lines or so) so needless to say you can't use all the functions. So now I have to use makefiles to point to other directories.

I've been trying to create makefiles but at the moment the errors just rack up so much that I really don't know what part of the process is at fault. Is it the C or the headers or the wrong libraries? I'm kind of clueless to where the libraries might even be.

Could someone please help me write a makefile for Linux headers and their libraries that is not in the usual `/usr/include` directory? The source files that I want to use will be in `usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0.32-generic/include`. Also if they are in the makefile how will I include them in the source?

I've been learning a lot of things in parallel and I think the curve is starting to get to me. :/

Comment: It's probably as easy as adding `usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0.32-generic/include` as an inclusion directory, e.g. using the `-I` option for GCC.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: Or something not 12 years old: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html (Although `-I` doesn't seem to have changed.)

Comment: @Biffen hahaha!
How can I see where the libraries are stored though?

Comment: @BaddaBoompshhh What do you mean by ‘libraries’? Header files, `.so` files, `.a` files?

Comment: @Biffen Well the header files must have libraries linked to them right? If I use a header file how can I be sure what to say -lxxx ?

Comment: @BaddaBoompshhh They don't *necessarily* have to have libraries (there are plenty of header-only ‘libraries’). Wherever you found the information to use a certain header file, you should also find information about which libraries to link.